# Doing a ToDoList in JS, receiving a not expected output when inserting an element

Tags: javascript, html

I'm doing a To Do List with HTML, CSS and JS. Problem is when I append to the list an element with a value that already exists. It should not be duplicated, however, it does.

This is the code. I'm not uploading the HTML, but if you need it just tell me (toDoList is an `ul` with `li` elements inside)

```
const inputBox = document.getElementById("input-box");
const btn = document.querySelector(".btn");
const toDoList = document.getElementById("list-container");

function checkTask(task) {
    const listElements = toDoList.getElementsByTagName("li");
    for (let i = 0; i < listElements.length; i++) {
        if (listElements[i].textContent.trim() === task) {
            return true; // La tarea ya existe
        }
    }
    return false; // La tarea no existe
}

function addTask() {
    const inputBoxValue = inputBox.value.trim();
    
    if (inputBoxValue === "") {
        alert("Please enter a task");
        return;
    }

    if (checkTask(inputBoxValue)) {
        alert("Task already exists");
        inputBox.value = "";
        return; // Evitar agregar tareas duplicadas
    }

    const li = document.createElement("li");
    li.textContent = inputBoxValue;
    toDoList.appendChild(li);
    inputBox.value = "";

    let span = document.createElement("span");
    span.innerHTML = "\u00d7"; // Comando para la x
    li.appendChild(span);
}

btn.addEventListener("click", addTask);
```

edit:

html added down here

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>ToDoList</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="toDo">
            <h2> To Do List<img src="./icon.png"></h2>
            <div class="row">
                <input type="text" id="input-box" placeholder="Add your task">
                <button class="btn">Add</button>
            </div>
            <ul id="list-container">
                <!--<li class="checked">Task 1</li>
                <li>Task 2</li>
                <li>Task 3</li> -->
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to add the html so we can have an accurate example to debug.

Comment: done! i have editted the post

Comment: If you log `listElements[i].textContent.trim()` within `checkTask()`, you will see that the text has an "x" appended to the end of it, so it will never match the new task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is something wrong while checking duplicate item. Your `listElements[i].textContent.trim()` check the text appended with `×`. For example if you already have a in you list and added new a from your input you are checking this value 'a' with `a×` so, it does match and added to the list.

Here, I have replaced '×' with empty string with `listElements[i].textContent.trim().replace("×", "")` code block. But you can follow the better approach to replace this value.

```js
const inputBox = document.getElementById("input-box");
const btn = document.querySelector(".btn");
const toDoList = document.getElementById("list-container");

function checkTask(task) {
  const listElements = toDoList.getElementsByTagName("li");
  for (let i = 0; i < listElements.length; i++) {
    if (listElements[i].textContent.trim().replace("×", "") === task) {
      return true; // La tarea ya existe
    }
  }
  return false; // La tarea no existe
}

function addTask() {
  const inputBoxValue = inputBox.value.trim();

  if (inputBoxValue === "") {
    alert("Please enter a task");
    return;
  }

  if (checkTask(inputBoxValue)) {
    alert("Task already exists");
    inputBox.value = "";
    return; // Evitar agregar tareas duplicadas
  }

  const li = document.createElement("li");
  li.textContent = inputBoxValue;
  toDoList.appendChild(li);
  inputBox.value = "";

  let span = document.createElement("span");
  span.innerHTML = "\u00d7"; // Comando para la x
  li.appendChild(span);
}

btn.addEventListener("click", addTask);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>ToDoList</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="toDo">
      <h2> To Do List<img src="./icon.png"></h2>
      <div class="row">
        <input type="text" id="input-box" placeholder="Add your task">
        <button class="btn">Add</button>
      </div>
      <ul id="list-container">
        <!--<li class="checked">Task 1</li>
                <li>Task 2</li>
                <li>Task 3</li> -->
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```